# Reducing Flask/Gunicorn request queue

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask/Gunicorn endpoint which takes a few seconds to return and gets hit pretty hard. Gunicorn seems to queue up a lot of requests and eventually process them all, but the requests which happen to be added at the back of the queue end up taking a really long time.

The app runs as `gunicorn -w 4 -b :8080`.

Is there any way to configure Flask/Gunicorn so that it will only keep X requests in the queue?

Answer (score 13):

Probably you've figured it out by now, but since I ran into this, I may as well answer it.

The "request queue" you mention, is called "backlog" and based on the [docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#backlog) you can change it by passing in the `--backlog` argument to your command, so it would look like:

```
gunicorn -w 4 --backlog 1024 -b :8080
```

Keep in mind though, that if the number of requests exceed the number you put there, your clients will start seeing errors.